# Dax measure that counts number of occurrence

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to create measure *Invoice Counter* that shows number of invoices per customer. This measure must reflect slicer in the page.

[image]

If in year slicer is selected year = 2022, measure should reflex this.

[image]

Sorry I don't paste my test code here, it was nonsense so far.

Thanks for help.

Comment: use ``ALLSELECTED`` in your ``Invoice Counter`` measure...

Answer (score 0):

Your modelling approach is a little awkward: Your table shows an *Invoice Counter* of 3 for the single *invoice* 11 in 2022 for "jack", and the sum of *Invoice Counter* is 14, although there are 6 different invoices only. This is at least confusing ...

Your *Invoice counter* measure should aggregate *invoice* like this:

```
Invoice Counter = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table'[invoice]),
    ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[customer])
)
```

but then you can't filter it by invoice again, because that will **undo** the above aggregation. Just put *customer*, *year* and *Invoice Counter* in one table and of cause you can filter that table by year, if you like:

[image]